# Responsive and always quadratic/1:1 ratio div

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm creating a simple game in CSS and JavaScript where I want the game field to be quadratic and it's width/height depending on the viewport height. However if the viewport width is less than the height I want the field size to update accordingly and keep the 1:1 ratio.

This is my code:

```
<div class="field">
    <div class="player">
    </div>
</div>

.field {
    width: 75vh;
    height: 75vh;
    background: #B2EBF2;
    border: 1.25vh solid #0097A7;
}
.field .player {
    width: 5vh;
    height: 5vh;
    background: #727272;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/achronos/1gayqwnk/)

It works when changing the window/viewport height, but not the width. How can I make the div responsive and always quadratic when the viewport width changes?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using CSS media queries to test if viewport is in portrait or landscape orientation. In Portrait, the width is the smallest distance and must be considered. In landscape, it's the height, that is the smallest one.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1gayqwnk/3/)

```
@media only screen and (orientation: portrait) {
    .field {
        width: 75vw;
        height: 75vw;
    }
}

@media only screen and (orientation: landscape) {
    .field {
        width: 75vh;
        height: 75vh;
    }
}

.field {
    background: #B2EBF2;
    border: 1.25vh solid #0097A7;
}

.field .player {
    width: 5vh;
    height: 5vh;
    background: #727272;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just give the field min-width and min-height

```
field {
width: 75vh;
height: 75vh;
max-width: 600px;
max-height: 300px;
background: #B2EBF2;
border: 1.25vh solid #0097A7;
}

.field .player {
width: 5vh;
height: 5vh;
max-width: 600px;
max-height: 300px;
background: #727272;
}
```

i hope it solve the problem